# New-ADUser "Unable to contact the server", but only when executed via WinRM from Ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, active-directory, winrm

I have written my very first PowerShell script to create Active Directory objects to be used for Oracle Kerberos authentication.  It works perfectly when run via a Scheduled Task using the user credentials created specifically for this purpose.  However when executed remotely via WinRM (from Ansible using the pywinrm module), it always fails:

```
PS>TerminatingError(New-ADUser): "Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running."
```

As per a suggestion in [this very informative blog post](https://theitbros.com/unable-to-find-a-default-server-with-active-directory-web-services-running/), I added a `Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Service ADWS` to my script, and it correctly identifies one of a number of domain controllers running Active Directory Web Services.  I also tried the `Test-NetConnection <DC> -port 9389` suggestion, and the DC(s) are reachable on that port.

Any idea what could be going wrong here, please, or what diagnostic steps I can take next?  I and my Windows colleagues are stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Does the scheduled task run a different PowerShell version than what is configured for WinRM?  If the PowerShell version used by WinRM happens to be running PowerShell 7.4 preview version 5 or 6, then this is an issue that recently appeared in preview 5 (and also exists in preview 6 released last week):

- https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20403
- https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20168

The issue seems to result in most of the Get-ADxxxx commands returning the error you have listed.

One of the posts mentions the issue being with the .NET version included, and: "*will be fixed when net8 rc2 comes out and pwsh ships with it.*" - But unfortunately does not give timing.

One work-around seen in the posts is to use the "-Server" parameter and specify an IP address of a Domain Controller (DC) vs name (which forces NTLM instead of Kerberos). I can confirm this works, though would not recommend... as hard-coding DC's in scripts, as well as using IP addresses vs DNS names, is very bad practice and setting the script up to fail in the future.

Comment: Whether I execute the script locally or remotely via ansible, the version recorded in the transcript is always "5.1.20348.1850".

In any case, I did try adding `-Server <ip>` to the AD functions in the script, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by elevating the permissions of the ansible task running the Powershell script:

```
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: '{{ user }}'
  vars:
   ansible_become_password: '{{ password }}'
```